# How to solve uniform continuity problem, Calculus by Michael Spivak.

Tags: calculus

> a) Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous on A, then so is $f + g$.
>
> b) Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous and bounded on A, then
>   $fg$ is uniformly continuous on A.
>
> c) Show that this conclusion does not hold if one of them isn't bounded.
>
> d) Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on A, that $g$ is uniformly continuous
>   on B, and that $f(x)$ is in B for all x in A. Prove that **(g o f)** is
>   uniformly continuous on A.

I already proved a) and b) but I wrote them for part c), I suppose I have to give a countarexample but I don't happen to have one.

But for part d) I am confused, I think that for $\epsilon>0$ we have to find a $\delta > 0$/ $\forall x,y $ if |$x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(g(x)) - f(g(y))| < \epsilon$

Is that right?

Comment: The way to solve is exactly what you described. For part (d), try to think what happens to $|g(x)-g(y)|$ under those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

c): $f(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous on $ \mathbb R$ but $f^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $ \mathbb R$.

d): yes, you are right.